# How to transpose columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

| SKU | CITY | MOV | TYPE | UNI | IMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 116 | 49 | Caducidad | 3 | 203.889 |
| 1 | 116 | 48 | Daño | 3 | 203.889 |
| 1 | 116 | 47 | Robo | NULL | NULL |

And I'm trying to transpose 'Type' column to display something like this

| SKU | CITY | TYPE_UNI_CADUCIDAD | TYPE_IMP_CADUCIDAD | TYPE_UNI_DAÑO | TYPE_IMP_DAÑO | TYPE_UNI_ROBO | TYPE_IMP_ROBO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 116 | 3 | 203.889 | 3 | 203.889 | NULL | NULL |

I tried case and pivot but not really working

```
SELECT SKU, CITY, 
case 
when MOV=49 then sum(Total_Imp) end as Type_Imp_Caducidad ,
case
when MOV=48 then sum(Total_Imp) end as Type_Imp_Daño ,
case
when MOV=47 then sum(Total_Imp) end as Type_Imp_Robo
from #movimientos 
where Id_Num_SKU=11466978
group by SKY, CITY, MOV
```

Comment: You need the aggregate the *whole* `CASE` expression.

Comment: @JNevill is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both comentsalready told you you need to aggreate the hole `CASE WHEN` to have an aggregation function

```
SELECT SKU, CITY, 
sum(case 
when MOV=49 then Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Caducidad ,
sum(case
when MOV=48 then Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Daño ,
SUM(case
when MOV=47 then Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Robo
from #movimientos 
where Id_Num_SKU=11466978
group by SKY, CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `MOV` from the `GROUP BY` and then aggregate the whole `CASE` expression

```sql
SELECT
  m.SKU,
  m.CITY, 
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 49 then m.Total_Uni end) as Type_Uni_Caducidad,
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 49 then m.Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Caducidad,
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 48 then m.Total_Uni end) as Type_Uni_Daño,
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 48 then m.Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Daño,
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 47 then m.Total_Uni end) as Type_Uni_Robo,
  SUM(case when m.MOV = 47 then m.Total_Imp end) as Type_Imp_Robo
from #movimientos m
where m.Id_Num_SKU = 11466978
group by
  m.SKY,
  m.CITY;
```